# Google Charts, define variables and arrayToDataTable

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Playing with Google Charts and I tried to implement a button to switch between two sets of data. But I can't seem to get the code right and end up with the following error so far:

test5.html:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined
at test5.html:71
(anonymous) @ test5.html:71

test5.html:98 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
at drawChart (test5.html:98)

Not sure if I am missing something major or just typos and such... Also, am I supposed to declare all the variables at the beginning (button, current, etc?), this was not done in the exemple I followed and I don't understand why? Any help would be welcome! Thank you all!

My code:

```
<html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data;
var chart;



  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});


  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    var rawData1 =
    [
    ['Contract',
    'Fees',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'Tax',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'A', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' },
    'A Taxes',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'B Fees', {role: 'style'} , { role: 'annotation' },
    {role: 'style'} ],

    ['CDE',
    150000,'#031359','Fees',
    0,'#1a42a7',,
    30000,'#1872a4','A',
    0,'#28abd5','',
    500 ,'#ff9900','CDE Fees',
    '#ff9900'],

    ['EFG',
    150000,'#031359','Fees',
    30000,'#1a42a7','Tax',
    30000, '#1872a4','B',
    30000,'#28abd5','B Taxes',
    ,'#ff9900','','']
    ];

    var rawData2 =
    [
    ['Contract',
    'Fees',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'VAT',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'B', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' },
    'B Taxes',{role: 'style'}, { role: 'annotation' },
    'CDE Fees', {role: 'style'} , { role: 'annotation' },
    {role: 'style'} ],

    ['CDE',
    450000,'#031359','Fees',
    0,'#1a42a7',,
    90000,'#1872a4','B',
    0,'#28abd5','',
    1800 ,'#ff9900','CDE Fees',
    '#ff9900'],

    ['EFG',
    450000,'#031359','Fees',
    90000,'#1a42a7','Tax',
    90000, '#1872a4','B',
    90000,'#28abd5','B Taxes',
    ,'#ff9900','','']
    ];



    var data = [];
      data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData1);
      data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData2);

    var options = {
                  'width':900,
                  'height':300,

                  animation:{
                    duration: 1500,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    startup: 'true'
                    },

                   legend: 'none',
                   bar: { groupWidth: '50%' },
                   isStacked: true

               };
    var current = 0;


    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    var button = document.getElementById('b1');

  function drawChart() {

    button.disabled = true;
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
            function() {
              button.disabled = false;
              button.value = 'Switch to ' + (current ? '150k' : '450k');
            });


    options['title'] = 'CDE v. EFG : how much do you save on a ' + (current ? '150k deal?' : '450k deal?');


    chart.draw(data[current], options);
  }



  drawChart();

  button.onclick = function() {
    current = 1 - current;
    drawChart();
  }

</script>
```

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width:900; height:400"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second error is an easy fix:

```
test5.html:98 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined at drawChart (test5.html:98)
```

Let's see what you did to cause that error:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("b1");
function drawChart() {
  button.disabled = true;
  // ...
}
```

Let's check your HTML Markup:

```html
<div id="chart_div" style="width:900; height:400"></div>
<!-- Oh no! There's no <button id="b1"> here anywhere! -->
```

When you call `document.getElementById(id)`, you have to make sure that there is a real element on the page with that `id`.

---

Your first error, I'm not so sure about, as I've never used the Google Charts API before. I think it comes from this part of your code:

```js
var data = [];
data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData1);
data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData2);
```

It seems that `google.visualization` is `undefined` for some reason. You may be connecting the script wrong or something.

As a side note, once you fix that error maybe you could refactor that piece of code to:

```js
var data = [rawData1, rawData2].map(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable);
```

That's all I got for your question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I now have a button (tested it with another working program). 
I am still working on the first issue tho: following your lead, I will be studying API documentation for the arrayToDataTable. 
If not that, I think I may have a fundamental issue with how I declare variables… and will need more studying of Java then. 
Anyway, thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: @Matthias you may have a typo in your comment, or maybe you don't understand something: JavaScript is *very* different from Java.

Comment: Yes, I meant Javascript!

Comment: Okay, no problem. Just wanted to make sure you weren't looking at the wrong documentation.